# Python: Checking if input value exist in dic and print the value from dict by using the input value

Tags: python, list

So I want to check if my `input(xd)` value exist in my `dict(main_data)` and I want to print the value from my `dict(main_data)` by using a value from the `input(xd)`

```
main_data = []
xdz = False

while True:
    name = input("enter the name: ")
    data1 = [int(i) for i in input("Phone number: ").split(" ")]
    data2 = [int(i) for i in input("Address: ").split(" ")]
    data3 = [int(i) for i in input("Job: ").split(" ")]
    data4 = [int(i) for i in input("Age: ").split(" ")]

    main_data.append({
        "name": name,
        "number": data1,
        "address": data2,
        "job": data3,
        "age": data4,
    })
    try = input("Input another data?:(Y/N)")
    if try == "N":
        break
    elif ulang == "n":
        break

xd = str(input("Enter the name you want to check: "))
xz = xd

if xz in main_data:
    print(main_data["name"][xz])
```

it is doesn't give me an output its stop at "Enter the name you want to check: "

Desired output:

```
Enter the name you want to check: john doe
[{'name': 'john doe', 'number': [123], 'address': [432], 'job': [321], 'age': [31]}]
```

did i using wrong print statement and if statement?

Comment: You code show compilations errors, you do'nt see them ? For the `try` first

Comment: `try` is an inbuilt keyword in python. use some other name for the variable..

Comment: Why i number, adress, job and age a list of one int ? Why the adress and job are ints ?

Comment: im sorry azro job,address,phone number,etc its not what im using in my code it just random word

Comment: and "try" it's the same its just random words, i use "another_data" in my real code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use `try` this is reserved keyword for exception handling
- don't use list comprehension (and not your one that convert each word to inn `[int(i) for i in  input().split(" ")`
- Your structure is a list of person, so you can't access to one or check the occurence of one by key, you need to iterate over the person

```
main_data = []

while True:
    name = input("enter the name: ")
    data1 = int(input("Phone number: "))
    data2 = input("Address: ")
    data3 = input("Job: ")
    data4 = int(input("Age: "))

    main_data.append({"name": name, "number": data1, "address": data2, "job": data3, "age": data4, })

    again = input("Input another data?:(Y/N)")
    if again.upper() == "N":
        break

name_to_look = str(input("Enter the name you want to check: "))
for person in main_data:
    if person['name'] == name_to_look:
        print(person)
```

---

If you want to lookup the person by name, use a `dict`

```
main_data = {}

while True:
    # ...
    main_data[name] = {"name": name, "number": data1, "address": data2, "job": data3, "age": data4, }
    # ...

name_to_look = str(input("Enter the name you want to check: "))
if name_to_look == main_data:
    print(main_data[name_to_look])
```

Answer (score 0):

- Do not use `try` as variable name as it is a keyword in Python.

You can try:

```
main_data = []
xdz = False

while True:
    name = input("enter the name: ")
    data1 = [int(i) for i in input("Phone number: ").split(" ")]
    data2 = [int(i) for i in input("Address: ").split(" ")]
    data3 = [int(i) for i in input("Job: ").split(" ")]
    data4 = [int(i) for i in input("Age: ").split(" ")]

    main_data.append({
        "name": name,
        "number": data1,
        "address": data2,
        "job": data3,
        "age": data4,
    })
    input_data = input("Input another data? (Y/N)")
    if input_data == "N" or input_data == "n":
        break

xd = str(input("Enter the name you want to check: "))

for index_number, data in enumerate(main_data):
    if data["name"] == xd:
        print(main_data[index_number])
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you used `try` in it

You can use `lower()` with input to make the alphabet smaller

At last use filter to quickly find stuff out of a list.

```
main_data = []
xdz = False

while True:
    name = input("enter the name: ")
    data1 = [int(i) for i in input("Phone number: ").split(" ")]
    data2 = [int(i) for i in input("Address: ").split(" ")]
    data3 = [int(i) for i in input("Job: ").split(" ")]
    data4 = [int(i) for i in input("Age: ").split(" ")]

    main_data.append({
        "name": name,
        "number": data1,
        "address": data2,
        "job": data3,
        "age": data4,
    })

    ulang = input("Input another data?:(Y/N)").lower()
    if ulang == "n":
        break


xd = (input("Enter the name you want to check: ")
xz = list(filter(lambda xx: xd == xx['name'], main_data))

print(xz)
```